# Getting bad performance with a simple TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to experiment with a simple TensorFlow model built with keras, but I can't figure out why I'm getting such poor predictions. Here's the model:

```py
x_train = np.asarray([[.5], [1.0], [.4], [5], [25]])
y_train = np.asarray([.25, .5, .2, 2.5, 12.5])

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu", input_shape=(x_train.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dense(9, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu"))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, shuffle=True, epochs=10)

print(model.predict(np.asarray([[5]])))
```

As you can see, it should learn to divide the input by two. However the loss is `32.5705`, and over a few epochs, it refuses to change whatsoever (even if I do something crazy like 100 epochs, it's always that loss). Is there anything you can see that I'm doing horribly wrong here? The prediction for any value it seems is `0.`.

It also seems to be randomly switching between performing as expected, and the weird behavior described above. I re-ran it and got a loss of `0.0019` after 200 epochs, but if I re-run it with all the same parameters a second later the loss stays at 30 like before. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some reasons that I can think of,

1. training set is too small
2. learning rate is high
3. last layer should just be a linear layer
4. for some runs the ReLU units are dying (see dead ReLU problem) and your network weights don't change after that so you see the same loss value.
5. In this case maybe a tanh activation will provide better conditioning for optimization

I made a few changes to your code based on what I commented, and I get decent results.

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation

x_train = np.random.random((50000, 1))#np.asarray([[.5], [1.0], [.4], [5], [25]])

y_train = x_train /2. #TODO: add small amount of noise to y #np.asarray([.25, .5, .2, 2.5, 12.5])

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, clipvalue=0.5)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation="tanh", input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Dense(9, activation="tanh"))
model.add(Dense(1, activation=None))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=opt, metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, shuffle=True, epochs=10)

print(model.predict(np.asarray([.4322])))
```

Output:

```
[[0.21410337]]
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems to wok. I had done this before and forgot what I did to make it work. It must have been making my training set bigger. I'm having trouble understanding when to use an activation layer on the output layer, some examples use one and some don't, do you know why it's better not to use one here?

Comment: I generally use something that is nicely differentiable in the output layer. You could use ReLU (I have not seen ReLU in output layer in many places), but if your final ReLU dies then your network has no hope of recovering.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information! News to me, I'll try experimenting with the output layer